# Android databackup

Tags: android, android-backup-service, backup-agent

I am trying to implement the data backup in my application using data [backup api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).

The `onBackup` method in the `BackupAgent` helper class is never called. The Document says that the `onBackup()` will be called some time in the future. Is there any specific time when the `onBackup` will be invoked? Will it be invoked only once a day?

I tried to force the data backup on an emulator and a Nexus 7 device, using the following command:

```
adb shell bmgr backup <package>
adb shell bmgr run
```

The `onBackup()` implementation was called on the emulator but on the device it was never called. Will the *bmgr tool* work on the device? Please help me to understand.

Comment: `bmgr ` works on my Nexus 5. Post your code here

Answer (score 1):

Check your Manifest file to see if under application you have `android:allowBackup="true"` as well as `android:backupAgent` having the correct path to your projects FileBackupAgent. Also, your meta-data should have your registered key, such as `android:value="your-registerd-key"`

Make sure your device is connected to a Wi-Fi network. Also, make sure in your device Settings, the Backup and Reset needs to have "Back up my data" checked, and "Backup account" has a valid gmail account, and "Automatic restore" is checked.

> > In addition, in a command window, your transport settings should be: *com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService

You can see this by typing: bmgr list transports If transport is set to local, then enter: `adb shell bmgr transport com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService`

Other `bmgr` commands to use to "kick" start your backup in https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard are:

```
 adb shell bmgr enabled 
 adb shell bmgr wipe "<package_name>"
 adb shell bmgr backup "<package_name>"
 adb shell bmgr run
```

Refresh your https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard to see the latest backup timestamp

Comment: The alternative to not forcing an immediate backup with the bmgr command, is to call .dataChanged() in your code so its queue up for a backup as the Google Backup Manager Service responds roughly every hour. See backup frequency measurements from this tester:  https://advancedweb.hu/2014/12/09/practical_measurement_of_the_android_backup_manager/

Comment: `bmgr list transports` not worked for me, use `adb shell bmgr list transports` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
adb shell bmgr transport android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
```

to change the transport to Local (even though the documentation

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup.html#TestingBackup

suggests Google transport, it will impose a backup limit, and you will be only able to do a backup every 24 hours).

Run this command to kick start the backup:

```
adb shell bmgr run
```

The 'run' command causes any scheduled backup operation to be initiated
immediately, without the usual waiting period for batching together
data changes.

Run this to see pending backups:

```
adb shell dumpsys backup
```